# How can I initialise each JQuery UI accordion so they open different items depending on data tag?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I am trying to initialise several JQuery UI accordions which open different items initially. I don't want to have to initialise every accordion separately, but would rather keep it all wrapped up in one function (also to make it easier for integration with CMS). I am trying to accomplish it this way:

```
<div class="accordion" data-initiallyopen="1">
    <h3>HEADER 1</h3>
    <div class="details">...</div>
    <h3>HEADER 2</h3>
    <div class="details">...</div>
</div>

$(".accordion").accordion({
    active: $(this).data("initiallyopen"),
    collapsible: true,
    heightStyle: "content"
});
```

This doesn't work unfortunately. No console error. $(this) is obviously not the right object - but is there a way to access the accordion from within the init?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dBNFd/), try:

```
$(".accordion").each(
    function () {
        $(this).accordion( {
            active: $(this).data("initiallyopen"),
            collapsible: true,
            heightStyle: "content"
        })
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the bootstrap accordion function, if you set the HTML class "collapse in" aswell as accordion, you can pick which accordions are left open - eg:

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">
                Collapsible Group Item #1
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse in">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
                Anim pariatur cliche...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo">
                Collapsible Group Item #2
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
                Anim pariatur cliche...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this example, the second accordion would be closed as its class is "accordion collapse", whereas the first one has "accordion collapse in".

Comment: I'm not using the bootstrap accordion, thanks for the tip though.